# Applying a filter to exclude a specific numerical value on a nested object's field with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation, querying

I am trying to calculate the aggregated average value of a field in my db via elasticsearch. 
I am not having any problems calculating the av value without any filtering :

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "avg_quantity": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "license_offer.unit_price"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

However I need to exclude from the aggregation docs that have a license_offer.unit_price of 0 (licence_offer is a nested object within license).

I tried different things, this is my latest attempt :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "license_offer.unit_price": {
                        "gte": 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "quantity_stats": {
            "stats": {
                "field": "license_offer.unit_price"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but I am getting an error :

```
 "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "no [query] registered for [license_offer.unit_price]",
```

How do you apply a filter to exclude a specific numerical value on a nested object's field with elastic search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct, you're simply missing the `range` keyword:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {                           <--- add this
                     "license_offer.unit_price": {
                        "gte": 0
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "quantity_stats": {
            "stats": {
                "field": "license_offer.unit_price"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can also move the filter inside the aggregation part:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "only_positive": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "license_offer.unit_price": {
            "gt": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "quantity_stats": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "license_offer.unit_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @val could you please show how you would do it by specifically excluding the value 0 ?

Comment: Use `gt` instead of `gte`?

Comment: Yes I just did that, but is there a way to do it without using a range logic but rather with an "exclusion"/filtering logic (something like "not 0")

Comment: Yes you can move the filter inside the aggregation part. See my updated answer